# Took too long to load the homepage , other pages on site met Internal Server Error

Tags: wordpress

It took like 1-2 mins to load the homepage . Besides , when I clicked other pages on menu , I got the problem "Internal Server Error" .
I've changed all URLs from localhost to new domain one but still taken too long to load the homepage and couldnt load other pages on the menu.

Here is my website url :"https://www.smtt.vn"
Any recommendation is aprreciate .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete all plugins from cpanel and check if it's opening fast(for slow connection), go to your dashboard and try to change permalinks from here https://www.smtt.vn/wp-admin/options-permalink.php (for internal server error), if problem persists talk to your hosting provider.